# Can CSS filters be completely disabled in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, filter

I have a page which applies the CSS style `filter: alpha(opacity=30);` to certain elements to cover IE8 users.  For me, this always works fine; the elements in question are always rendered the way I would expect.  However, for some other users using precisely the same build of IE8, these elements occasionally render as though the opacity filter was missing or disabled.  It's not actually missing; they can open the IE developer tools panel, select the element in question, and see the style in the right-hand pane, but IE seems to be ignoring it.  For these users, resetting the browser configuration (using Tools | Internet Options | Advanced | Reset...) makes the problem go away, but eventually it comes back.

I know that there are conditions under which IE8 won't apply the opacity filter to a given element (for example, if the element doesn't have layout), but in this case, the exact same element on the same page will render differently from one visit to the next, so I don't think it's a problem with the HTML.  It almost seems like these users are somehow doing something which affects their browser configuration in a way that causes IE8 to completely ignore the alpha filter on all pages, until the browser configuration is manually reset.  Is that even possible?

Comment: Could you provide code please so we can test this

Comment: Which 'elements' are you referring to?  IE8 only applies filters that are 'On having layout.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can CSS filters be completely disabled in IE8?

Yes, this feature can be disabled.

The `filter` feature is basically a wrapper for an ActiveX control that does the work. If ActiveX controls are disabled, then the filter feature will also be disabled.

The most likely cause for what you've described is some sort of automated security software which is disabling ActiveX.

Having ActiveX enabled in the browser is considered a security issue, since it potentially exposes the user to unknown code that can have deep-level access to their system. Therefore, many users choose to disable the feature.

Some security products may also do this for their users automatically. The effect you're seeing sounds like this is happening, with the security tool switching it off whenever it finds it enabled during a regular routine system check.

You may also have issues with users of newer IE versions (IE10 onward), which have the ActiveX feature disabled by default. This obviously isn't a problem in IE10 standards mode, since you have all the standard CSS3 features instead so don't need `filter` (and indeed `filter` isn't available in IE10 standards mode anyway), but if you're using IE10 in IE8 compatiblity mode, then it is quite likely that your `filter` code will not work, even though you're in a mode where you might expect it to be available.

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what's happening.  The users who are experiencing this issue are affected by a corporate security standard that disables the "Binary and script behaviors" option under "ActiveX controls and plug-ins".  Forcibly re-enabling that option causes the page to display correctly, until the next time the security tool disables it.